# Creating a "compiler" to edit strings

Tags: c#, string, compiler-construction

Hello atm I'm fiddling around with creating a compiler this is my attempt at converting random language

Input:

```
import System;
import System.Collections.Generic;
import System.Linq;
import System.Text;
import System.IO;

class Compiler
BEGIN;

    private List : string Strings;

    function construct()
    BEGIN;
        Strings = new List : string();
    END;

    function void start ( a : int, b : int, c : int )
    BEGIN;

    END;

END;
```

Output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Compiler
{

    private List < string Strings;


    {
        Strings = new List < string();
    }

    private void start ( int a,    int b,    int c,    
    {

    }

}
```

As you can see it kind of works to compile my code to c# except for the list how I'm compiling it is just by editing strings I tried without a tutorial just for fun and try stuff(please don't look at my compiler code it's just made with random stuff i've known without google or anything), now I've searched google for better solitions but I haven't found anything yet.

This is my compiler code:

```
public void Compile(String input, String output)
        {
            DirectoryCopy(input, output, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Searching input directory for files.");
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(input, "*.upl",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            Console.WriteLine("Found " + filePaths.Count() + " file(s) In this directory and all sub directorys");
            Console.WriteLine("Start compiling? (Y/N)");
            if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
                for (int p = 0; p < filePaths.Length; p++ )
                {
                    String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePaths[p]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        lines[i] = lines[i].StartsWith("import ") ? lines[i].Replace("import", "using") : lines[i];

                        if (lines[i].Contains("function "))
                        {
                            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("function", "private");
                            string[] split = lines[i].Split(' ');
                            for (int s = 0; s < split.Length; s++)
                            {
                                if (split[s].Contains(":"))
                                {
                                    if (split[s - 1].Contains("("))
                                    {
                                        if (split[s + 1].Contains(","))
                                        {
                                            string[] split2 = split[s + 1].Split(',');
                                            split[s - 1] = "( " + split2[0] + " " + split[s - 1][1] + ",";
                                            split[s] = string.Empty;
                                            split[s + 1] = split[s + 1].Split(',')[1];
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            split[s - 1] = "( " + split[s + 1] + " " + split[s - 1][1];
                                            split[s] = string.Empty;
                                            split[s + 1] = string.Empty;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (split[s + 1].Contains(")"))
                                    {
                                        split[s + 1] = split[s + 1].Replace(")", "");
                                        split[s - 1] = split[s + 1] + " " + split[s - 1] + " )";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        split[s - 1] = split[s + 1].Replace(",", "") + " " + split[s - 1] + ", ";
                                        split[s] = string.Empty;
                                        split[s + 1] = string.Empty;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            split[split.Length - 1] = string.Empty;
                            split[split.Length - 2] = string.Empty;
                            lines[i] = String.Join(" ", split);
                        }

                        if (lines[i].Contains("if") || lines[i].Contains("foreach"))
                        {
                            bool insert = false;
                            for (int i2 = 2; i2 < lines[i].Length; i2++)
                            {
                                if (!char.IsLetter(lines[i][i2]))
                                {
                                    if (insert == false)
                                    {
                                        char[] letters = lines[i].ToCharArray();
                                        letters[i2] = '(';
                                        lines[i] = String.Join("", letters);
                                        insert = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            lines[i] = !lines[i].EndsWith("BEGIN;") ? lines[i] + ")" : lines[i];
                            lines[i] = lines[i].Contains(":") ? lines[i].Replace(":", "in") : lines[i];
                        }

                        if (lines[i].Contains("Message"))
                        {
                            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("Message", "MessageBox.Show(");
                            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(";", " );");
                        }

                        if (lines[i].Contains("List") && lines[i].Contains(":"))
                        {
                            int spaces = 0;
                            char[] letters = lines[i].ToCharArray();
                            for (int c = 0; c < letters.Length; c++)
                            {
                                letters[c] = char.Equals(letters[c], ':') ? '<' : letters[c];
                                if (char.Equals(letters[c], '<'))
                                    break;
                                spaces = char.IsWhiteSpace(letters[c]) ? spaces + 1 : spaces;
                            }
                            lines[i] = String.Join("", letters);
                            string[] spacesArr = lines[i].Split(' ');
                        }

                        lines[i] = lines[i].EndsWith("BEGIN;") || lines[i].StartsWith("BEGIN") ? lines[i].Replace("BEGIN;", "{") : lines[i];
                        lines[i] = lines[i].EndsWith("END;") || lines[i].Contains("END;") ? lines[i].Replace("END;", "}") : lines[i];
                    }
                    double completion = ((double)(p + 1) / (double)filePaths.Length) * 100;
                    Console.WriteLine("Compiled file " + (p + 1) + " of the total " + filePaths.Length + " file(s). (" + (int)completion + "%)");
                    int pathleng2 = output.Split('\\').Count();
                    string[] filepath = filePaths[p].Split('\\');
                    string subPath = String.Join("\\", filepath, pathleng2, (filePaths[p].Split('\\').Count() - input.Split('\\').Count()));
                    subPath = subPath.Replace("upl", "cs");
                    File.WriteAllLines(output + "\\" + subPath, lines);
                }
            }
        }
```

So my question is:

Does anyone have a good idea how to tackle this problem? split a string in words or something like that? perhaps a tokenizer? IF thats possible in c#

If you have questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: I wouldn't code everything into a split/if hassle. Create a tokenizer and a lexer. Maybe check out antlr?

Comment: I knew splitting was stupid to do but I just made it with some things I know let me google that I've heard about tokenizer and lexer but I didn't find much info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a C# code generator rather than a compiler: it takes your own language as input and creates C# code as output.

A good tool for doing this kind of thing is the C# [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) parser. This parser will allow you to define and parse your own language. This will give you a parse tree; which is a representation of your language in some object model. Once you have this parse tree you will need to convert this into C#.

In my experience defining the language and parsing it with Irony is pretty easy. Converting the parse tree to the final format is the hard bit.

I've used Irony to parse XAML markup extensions in [Xamlr](https://xamlr.codeplex.com/): the source code that might give you some ideas of how to get started.

Comment: Hi I know I'm just parsing my code from high-level to high-level code, I've seen irony and it looks pretty sweet but what I'm after is a good way to parse one code to another or even better compiling my code to a intermediate-level code. I've seen the dragon book should I try reading that?

Comment: I've never written a compiler, so I'm speculating here, but if you think about it the first step must be to parse files into object model that can be inspected and understood by the compiler. That is the bit that Irony will do for you. After that you need to convert that object model into machine code that the computer can execute. Maybe look at the https://github.com/bamboo/boo/wiki boo language, it is built on the CLR so it defines its own language and generates IL. I doubt you would want to get deeper than that!

Comment: Looks really sweet thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

For the basic task you mentioned any parser generator will fit -- C# is not short of them. Already mentioned [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/), or [Coco/R](http://ssw.jku.at/coco/), [GOLD](http://goldparser.org/), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), [LLLPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664785/A-New-Parser-Generator-for-Csharp), [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/sprache), or my [NLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/).

One remark -- the code you showed us is incorrect C#.

If you want to compile, this is quite different task, because I assume you compile to very specific target -- .Net. So your code has to be usable from other .Net code and vice-versa. So having this is mind you are "simply" creating another .Net language. The problem is not with compiling but with keeping it correct within .Net.

Probably I would not go with anything else then [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I know I'm doing it wrong but I was just trying out some stuff to learn, thats why I'm trying not to use stuff like antlr or irony

Comment: @StijnBernards, I don't follow -- if you want to learn you should use those tools. You will learn a lot. THEN if you would like to learn even more, you could write your own tool from the scratch. OK, you have the will, enthusiasm, so don't waste it on reinventing the square wheel, do it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Don't shove all the logic in a single method. Create a parser class which implements helper methods to help you shift over each character, kind of like a .NET reader but without a stream as input. I'm not demotivating you from your project, but your attempt doesn't really go anywhere. Before you continue, consider writing simpler parsers first, like CSV or BB-code. It is a great opportunity. Also remember that you do not directly convert text from one format to another, you need an intermediate class to carry the parsed elements first, then pass it to the code generator. Note that the term compiler is used for components that generate byte code rather than text.

Comment: I knew that before I started I just did a random try without googling or looking at how I would tackle it. I just tried and did stuff. But my real question is how can I make an easy parser/compiler what should I use how do I implement a tokenizer or something like that.

Comment: You need a more systematic and organized approach. Just to experiment, create a class that implements [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) and use it to shift over a series of characters with the Read() method, based on each symbol (or word) you determine the next action in the process. If the text does not match up to the expectation of the parser, then an exception should be thrown. I really advice you to try something else first (and something more fun too), like a bbcode to HTML converter.

Comment: Yeah I'll try that also how about creating a lexer? I've found this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drew/archive/2009/12/31/a-simple-lexer-in-c-that-uses-regular-expressions.aspx

Comment: What you want is a parser, not a lexer. A lexer accepts elements in any order and does the grammar check afterwards, a parser understands how elements relate to each other natively, this makes it easier to implement and its faster too.

Comment: Hmmm let me check for a moment.